# keep keys of dictionary while sorting the values

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have got the following sort function:

```
orderedX = np.array(list(to_sort.values()))\
[np.array(list(to_sort.values())).argmax(axis=1).argsort(), :]
```

but I want to change it such that, orderedX becomes a dictionary with the items of to_sort, instead of just a list of its values. So the way it is sorted is correct, but is there someway I can also keep track of the keys while doing this?

to_sort is a dict with keys and values, where each value is a np.array

Comment: Can you show a small example input and output that illustrate what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with dictionaries is that they generally don't preserve order. Even with Python 3.6's changes to the implementation of dict, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) say that "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation [...] should not be relied upon". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)'s another SO question where this is explained in detail, look especially for Martijn Pieters' answer.

That being said, there's still `collections.OrdererDict` that does have order preservation. Here's how you create one with the desired sorting from your data. Note that I tried to simplify the sort algo a little bit, which, as far as I understood it, sorts by the maximum of the array in `to_sort`'s values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(to_sort.items(), key=lambda item:np.max(item[1])))
```

Iterating over it like this will give you both keys and values with values in sorted order:

```
for key, value in ordered.items():
    print(key, value)
```